# Simple if statement vs. normal if statement

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, bytecode, curly-braces

At Java byte code level, is there any difference between an simple if-statement (Example 1) and a normal if-statement (Example 2):

Example 1:

```
if (cond) statement;
```

Example 2:

```
if (cond) {
    statement;
}
```

The background of the question, is that I saw in "high performance" classes like `java.awt.Rectangle` and `Point` only the variant without curly braces.

Is there any speed benefit, or is that only code style?

Comment: Why don't you analyze it yourself? And see what you get.

Comment: I have no experience with byte code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aparte from the maintainability of your code, in terms of performance is exactly the same. You will not gain speed up from removing `{}`, since `{}` it is not an instruction by it self.

I normal use with `{}` because makes the code easy to read (IMO) and less propitious to making errors.

This example:

```
public void A(int i) {
     if (i > 10) {
        System.out.println("i");
        }
    }

    public void B(int i) {
        if (i > 10)
            System.out.println("i");
    }
```

byte code generated:

```
 // Method descriptor #15 (I)V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  public void A(int i);
     0  iload_1 [i]
     1  bipush 10
     3  if_icmple 14
     6  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [16]
     9  ldc <String "i"> [22]
    11  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [24]
    14  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 5]
        [pc: 6, line: 6]
        [pc: 14, line: 8]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 15] local: this index: 0 type: program.TestClass
        [pc: 0, pc: 15] local: i index: 1 type: int
      Stack map table: number of frames 1
        [pc: 14, same]

  // Method descriptor #15 (I)V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  public void B(int i);
     0  iload_1 [i]
     1  bipush 10
     3  if_icmple 14
     6  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [16]
     9  ldc <String "i"> [22]
    11  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [24]
    14  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 11]
        [pc: 6, line: 12]
        [pc: 14, line: 13]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 15] local: this index: 0 type: program.TestClass
        [pc: 0, pc: 15] local: i index: 1 type: int
      Stack map table: number of frames 1
        [pc: 14, same]
```

As you can see the are the same.

Answer (score 5):

The two are exactly the same. The Java compile will produce the same code.

Keep in mind, however, that in the non-bracket case, you will not be able to add multiple sub-statements inside the if-block the way you would be able to in the bracketed case

Comment: There should be no difference. I have not tested in using some bytecode inspection, but if there was a difference, than these two statements would be realized differently in compiler tree API (and there is no difference between these two)

Comment: and even if there would be some difference - Java has just in time compiler with HotSpot...i really doubt, if these micromicromicro optimizations might have even measurable effect

Answer (score 2):

The two examples you gave do the same exact thing.  Your first example is a **simple if-then-statement**, while your second example is a normal **if-then statement**.

The time it takes to execute those two statements is the same, since the braces are not an instruction, and therefore do not effect speed.  I would still use the normal if statement though, so you can have as many statements as you want within the if-statement.

Comment: I am interested in the extreme small differenece because i need it for thousands of rectangle.inside calls each second on a mobile device

Comment: That's fine, but I would focus on other, larger performance-hogging issues before you focus on such small ones

Comment: the larger pefrormance hogging is solved, by using a spatial index.

Comment: So remember to use float instead of double, it will raise performance a lot